# Duda en cómo hacer este Constructor

Tags: java

Buenas estoy trabajado con cadenas de texto que recibo a los cuales tengo que separarlos por comas , o por lo que me digan . En este caso tengo una clase llamada Espacio(clase padre) y otra clase llamada Despacho(clase hija)  
Y tengo esto : Para Espacio --> “A0.10,0,100,TEORIA” , la cual defino así

```
 public EspacioImpl(String espacio){
    //“A0.10,0,100,TEORIA”
    String[] campos = espacio.split(",");
    if(campos.length!=4){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cadena no valida");
    }
    //TipoEspacio tipo,String nombre , Integer capacidad , 
    //Integer planta
    String nombre = campos[0].trim();
    this.nombre=nombre;

    Integer planta = new Integer(campos[1].trim());
    this.planta=planta;

    Integer capacidad = new Integer(campos[2].trim());
    checkCapacidad(capacidad);
    this.capacidad=capacidad;

    this.tipo = TipoEspacio.valueOf(campos[3].trim());

}
```

El problema llega cuando tengo la clase hija Despacho la cual se define de tal forma la cadena de texto que recibe : “F1.43,1,3” (recibe un parametro menos que la clase padre Espacio) y tengo definido el constructor de esta forma

```
public DespachoImpl(String despacho){
    //“F1.43,1,3”
    super(despacho);
    String[] campos = despacho.split(",");
    if(campos.length!=3){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cadena incorrecta");
    }
}
```

Como podría para rreglar que recibiera un parámetro menos? Sugerencias o ayudas?
Saludos

Comment: Pienso que si `DespachoImpl` y `EspacioImpl` no comparten cosas en común desde el constructor y cosas como número de campos entonces no debería haber herencia. Luce más a un problema de diseño que de programación.

Answer (score 2):

No entro en valoraciones de diseño, pues desconozco el problema, te propongo una clase base donde controles por medio del constructor el delimitador, el numero de elementos que debe contener la cadena y la cadena es si misma.

Esta clase ademas te permite especificar distintos delimitadores en las subclases, y crear una validación común para todas la clases en lo relativo al numero de elementos recibidos, algo así te puede ayudar:

```
public abstract class Espacio {

  protected String delimiter;
  protected int nItems;
  protected String data;

  public Espacio(String delimiter, int nItems, String data) {
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
    this.nItems = nItems;
    this.data = data;
  }

  public Espacio(int nItems, String data) {
    this(",",nItems,data);
  }

  public String[] getItems() {
    if(data!=null && !data.isEmpty()) {
      String[] items=data.split(delimiter);
      if(items.length==nItems) {
        return items;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("cadena no valida");
  }

  public abstract void processData();

}
```

Las clases que extienden esta seria del tipo:

```
public class Planta extends Espacio {
  private String nombre;
  private Integer planta;
  private Integer capacidad;
  //private TipoEspacio tipo; // recomiendo usar un Enum

  public Planta(String data) {
    super(4,data);
  }

  @Override
  public void processData() {
    String[] campos = this.getItems();

    nombre = campos[0].trim();
    planta = new Integer(campos[1].trim());
    capacidad = new Integer(campos[2].trim());
    checkCapacidad(capacidad);

    //Implementa esto tu        
    //tipo = TipoEspacio.valueOf(campos[3].trim());

  }

  private boolean checkCapacidad(Integer value) {
    // Haz tu implementacion de validacion
    return true;
  }

}

public class Despacho extends Espacio {

  public Despacho(String data) {
    super(3,data);
  }

  @Override
  public void processData() {
    // Implementa aqui la carga de tus propiedades
  }

}
```

Espero que te ayude...